# Sk6812 addressable rgbw strip with mobo argb header

Tags: drivers, motherboard, headers, led

I was wondering if I could add an rgbw strip to my pc. I rouled out the 4pin connector for obvious reasons (no channel for w). Then, I saw a 3 pin addressable led strip with rgbw. Is there a way to control such a strip with the argb header on the motherboard (I have an asus z370). Since I use mainly linux is there a driver for it?

This is one of such strips
https://a.aliexpress.com/_Ev4wnXh

Comment: Those strips are absolutely not designed to be ran off a computers PSU

Comment: But why is that? Ws2812b strips are compatible it seems and are quite similar

Comment: Ws2812b is absolutely not compatible with the ASUS RGB header on your motherboard. Those LED strips are designed to be externally powered. As to how I know, I looked at the product, and made an educated determination

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes, you can, but there are bunch of things to consider.

There are many PC lighting products built on the SK6812 circuitry. I have the [Phanteks M5](https://www.phanteks.com/Neon.html) in my PC, and it is made up of SK6812 LED circuits. There are also several other products that use SK6812. A simple [ALI search](https://www.aliexpress.com/w/wholesale-SK6812-pc.html) will show you tons of options that are ASUS AURA Sync compatible.

If you want to purchase a strip such as the one you have linked in your original question, you will need to solder on three wires to the end of the strip, attach them to a 3-pin JST SM connector, and then get a 5V ARGB to 3-pin JST connector. The problem is that your MoBo will only put out so much power. You will likely not be able to power more than 60–120 SK6812 LED circuits, depending on the quality of the components in your RGB strip (and it may be even less that that). Cheap FPCBs have a lot of resistance. Some of the LED modules have a lot of power draw. Using too many RGB pixels will cause them to lose their color fidelity or just flicker out and not work. Although I haven't seen it, you may also damage the header on your MoBo.

Lastly, you will need some sort of software where you can control the drivers used to address each RGB (or RGBW) circuit. SignalRGB allows you to choose different products and drivers. It *should* work straight out of the box, but it may not, so you need to know what you are doing. I also don't know how easy Linux is to work with when addressing RGBs.

I hope that helps.